# Unable to load / route to HTML page using router-outlet

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to route to a login page in my main page
Main Page is : `KMS.html` which goes like this  (skipping scripts and all  )

```
<html>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app component for that page

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {globalFrameComponent} from './dashboard/landing/globalFrameComponent';
import {loginComponent} from '../login/loginComponent';
//import {HttpService} from './common/services/httpService';


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'ems.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS]   //HttpService
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: loginComponent, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/somethingelse', name: 'EMS', component: globalComponent }

])
@Injectable()
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Folder Structure:

In Root I have app folder which contains appComponent and `main.js`,  login folder which contains login Component, and `kms.html` page

I'm getting below error

> Error loading http://localhost:50102/login/loginComponent as "../login/loginComponent" from http://localhost:50102/app/appComponent.js

Comment: How does you folder structure look like. From the error it means that loginComponent is not in the path you have provided.

Comment: @MwaaJoseph: added Folder structure